# json doesn't install

Tags: ruby, jsonp

I am having a problem getting my ruby system up and running. Specifically, I get the following error when trying 
    gem install json

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

```
make
generating parser-i386-mingw32.def
compiling parser.c
gcc.exe: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1
```

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.
Results logged to c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/pa

I know that my gcc works. I don't get the same error when installing

```
`gem install json_pure
```

However, when I try a

```
bundle install
```

I get the error. I am extremely new to ruby and rails, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

install [devkit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller) with --force option

Comment: I got a very similar error where apparently json 1.3.6 is a dependency for my gems and this fixed my issue.